# General help for deciphering/explaining sed one-liners?

Tags: sed

I've just stumbled upon some cryptic sed expression in a legacy script. Could you give me some hints how to start decoding it?

Best thing would be some automatic tool translating sed incantations to English, but for a close runner up, I'd be very grateful for some nice index of (all) sed commands. Otherwise, I'm certainly highly interested in any help at all on how to quickly attack the problem (other than having to read the manual cover to cover...).

(*Side note:* as you may have guessed, I don't want to just paste the expression here, as I'd like to be able to do it easier and faster next time I stumble on some similar line noise...)

I'd be *very* grateful for help!

**Edit:** regexps themselves aren't problem, by the way, I'm good enough at them.

Comment: Let me get this right: you want a general way to be able to lean the intricacies of a specific programming language without actually learning the language and without consulting any well-known guides on that language?

Comment: Nope, I don't want to learn the language, that's the point. On the other hand, I have a bunch of scripts I must translate to some more readable language ASAP, and I want to be able to do it again if I have a similar case in future. Thus, more interested in some kinda EBNF+semantics reference, than "Your first sed script"-like narrative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think there is automatic tool that can 'transalte' sed commands to english. however you may want to check http://aurelio.net/sedsed/ . it will help you to understand one sed script, what it does, and how.

anyway, if you list some examples would be good.

Comment: Hm, this is starting to give me some more information via "--tokenize", but still not sure where to search for more elaborate explanations. The manual at http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html seems also surprisingly useful for starters, thanks to quite good indentation, but I'm still having some problems at the moment.

Comment: Accepted. In case of no better answers, this one was particularly useful, as I didn't stumble upon sedsed in Google, and it helped me decode one difficult part of the original expression. OTOH, sedsed did fail flat for me on some other complicated scripts :/ ... But stil, big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.5) might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

*Unix in a Nutshell* by Robbins has a very nice chapter on sed. Clear and concise descriptions of the commands.

Comment: Is it available online for free, or something? I don't want to invest too much in this problem.

Comment: I don't think it is. But almost the entire sed chapter is viewable in the preview at [scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/15490498/Unix-in-a-Nutshell). Try page 618.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to learn the sed language in-depth. Unforunately, the sed documentation is more like a reference. Here's [a nice step by step guide](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) that doesn't take too long to read.

Comment: Just to remind, I wrote explicitly that I'm interested here in solutions _"other than having to read the manual cover to cover"_. That said, the page you link to is sure a worthy resource, I've already googled it and it helped me understand some advanced commands like branching.

Answer (score 0):

I found ["Sed One-Liners Explained"](http://www.catonmat.net/series/sed-one-liners-explained) to be very informative as well as fun.

Comment: from my understanding, he has problem with legacy script, but not classic sed-oneliners, or I misunderstood him... :(

Comment: That's fair enough. My answer stands, though. If you work through these, you'll have a better understanding of simple one-liners and a grasp of the obscure, making it easier for you for you to deal with your legacy system.

Comment: The main problem is, that this would require me to spend _way too much time_ while still giving too little and uncertain gain with regards to the problem stated in _this particular question_.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted, "I don't want to just paste the expression here, as I'd like to be able to do it easier and faster next time I stumble on some similar line noise..." as, "I'd like to learn how to interpret these myself."